# How to use @SqlResultSetMapping in Symfony2, doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sqlresultsetmapping

There is an example about `@SqlResultSetMapping` in
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

I do not understand where and how i should use it? In controller action? In some custom class or trait?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it wherever you have access to repository class for entity in which you define it, i.e. from controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository("SomeCertainBundle:YourEntity");
$results = $repo->createNativeNamedQuery("name-of-the-query")->execute();
```